# Dynamically modify item data in player's inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I would like to modify the coordinates that a Lodestone Compass which is already in a player's inventory points to, where the coordinates are stored in scoreboards. I'm aware that it's possible to do this sort of thing with fixed values using item modifiers, as is explained in the responses to other questions here, but is there a way to set up the same thing where instead the data comes from a scoreboard?

Comment: can't check ingame or write out a long answer at the moment, so here is my guess: Write a custom [item modifier](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Item_modifier) that uses `copy_nbt` to copy the new position from the NBT storage, which you first set manually from the scoreboards. 4 commands (and a custom modifier) in total.